# cant get information from input into the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I have made a html page where you can write something in an input field and show it after submitting it on the same page. But when i try to put the written information in the input field in a mysql database it doesnt recieve anything in that database.

My Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var message = $("input").val();
    var old = $("#content").html();
    $("#content").html(old + '<p><span style="font-variant:small-caps">
    <span style="font-size:1.5em"><b><span style="text-transform:capitalize">
    <?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?></span> : </b></span>
    <span style="font-size:1.6em">' + message + 
    "</span></span></p>");
    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="startseite.php">
<div id="message">
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<input type="submit" name="hallo">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>

<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "db", "123456")
or die("Fehler im System");

mysql_select_db("db")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich");


$user = $_SESSION["username"];
$message = $_POST["spind"];

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO chat
(user, message)

VALUES
($user, $message)";

mysql_query($eintrag);


mysql_close($verbindung);
}
?>
```

Comment: ignoring that you are wide open to sql injection by using unsanitized user input directly, you need to quote your values -> `VALUES ('$user', '$message')`

Comment: start by adding single quotes around your $_POST['spind'], and session, and around your variables in the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

You are not pressing the correct button I think.

```
<input type="submit" name="hallo">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>
```

the submit button doesn't have any value, the button is empty so you're pressing the button and this is not submitting the form, there is no code I can see to make that button a submit button.

Maybe I miss to read something.

Comment: the problem was because of the quotes of VALUES. Thank you Sean